# The vector.insert method isn't working, what is wrong?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to write a pseudo-Brainfuck-compiler in C++, and the `vector.insert()` method isn't working. The compiler is giving me this error:

```
no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list            
argument types are: (int, char)            
object type is: d::vector<char, std::allocator<char>>
```

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> Array = { '\0' };
    std::vector<std::tuple <int, int> > loop_starts = { };
    unsigned int ptr = 0;

    std::ifstream file("BrainfuckCode.txt");
    std::vector<std::string> Code = { };

    int i = 0;
    std::string Line;
    while (true)
    {
        i++;
        getline(file, Line);
        if (Line == "\0")
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Code.push_back(Line);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Code.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Code[i].size(); j++)
        {
            switch (Code[i][j])
            {
            case '+':
                Array[ptr]++;
                break;

            case '-':
                Array[ptr]--;
                break;

            case '>':
                if (ptr == Array.size() - 1) Array.push_back('\0');
                ptr++;
                break;

            case '<':
                if (ptr == 0) Array.insert(0, '\0');
                else ptr--;
                break;

            case '.':
                putchar(Array[ptr]);
                break;

            case ',':
                Array[ptr] = getchar();
                break;

            case '[':
                loop_starts.push_back(std::make_tuple(i, j));
                break;

            case ']':
                if ((int)Array[ptr] != 0)
                {
                    i = std::get<0>(loop_starts[loop_starts.size() - 1]);
                    j = std::get<1>(loop_starts[loop_starts.size() - 1]);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: The [documantation of `insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) says the first argument needs to be an iterator, not an index. So you need `Array.insert(Array.begin(), '\0')`

Comment: read the full error message. gcc nicely points you at the first argument https://godbolt.org/z/4eWxxqvfr which is the one that doesnt match

Comment: FYI: `std::get<0>(loop_starts[loop_starts.size() - 1]);` could simply be: `std::get<0>(loop_starts.back());`

Comment: @molbdnilo `push_front()` is not in `std::vector`, but in `std::list`. a `vector` can't efficiently insert in the front.

Answer (score 2):

Insert works with iterators as first argument, not indices.
So `.insert(0, '\0')` should be `.insert(v.begin(), '\0')`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert